# Why does mysql sometimes reorder tables from the Primary Key?

Tags: mysql

I've noticed that sometimes my SQL will reorder data in a table and when I make calls to get it, its in that same order which is out of order sequentially.
Example:
ID is the primary key but sometimes it puts a new entry at the top of the list. When my pho calls the data, now it is out of order.
why is Mysql doing this?

http://cleehamilton.com/Screenshot_2014-10-14-11-47-51_1.jpg

Comment: If you don't explicitly specify a sort order, you can't expect one.

Comment: rows in (my)sql have no order (the real answer is a bit more complicated, but this is a good summary)

Comment: @DCoder do you mean specify in MYSQL or in php?

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause, the order of rows returned by MySQL in response to any sort of query is, formally, unpredictable.  Sometimes MySQL returns those rows in an order that looks like it makes sense, but if you don't have `ORDER BY` in your query, **that is always an accident.**

This can prove confusing to somebody who's unfamiliar with big complex software systems. A lot of people building their first data base application get caught by this. Sometimes the order of small result sets is (accidentally) a natural order, but as the system grows the order changes.